# Running gradient-free optimization methods in parallel with OpenMDAO and PyOptSparse

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, openmdao

I would like to run ALPSO and NSGA2 from OpenMDAO using the PyOptSparse driver in parallel. The catch is that I don't want to run the model itself in parallel (which I have done frequently in OpenMDAO), I just want to run the optimization computations in parallel (e.g. distribute the calculations for swarm members of ALPSO). I have been looking through the documentation and source for all of the above mentioned codes, but I have not found a way to do this. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Note: I am currently using OpenMDAO 1.7.3, but I am open to answers involving later versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that those optimizers support parallel execution. It would most likely require modifications to the code in ALPSO/NSGA2, pyoptsparse, and the pyoptsparse driver to support this.

In OpenMDAO 2.2 (the latest version), we do have a simple GA driver that can run the evaluation of points in the population in parallel, so maybe that is an option. (it is pretty simple though, and only supports single objective.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was not sure about NSGA 2, but I thought I saw parallel code for ALPSO in PyOptSparse. If ALPSO can be run in parallel, could the approach I described be done from OpenMDAO.

Comment: It looks like if you set the 'parallelType option to 'EXT', then ALPSO does support external parallelization by asking for all of the objective/constraint evaluations for the swarm at once. So that's the first part.  I don't know if pyoptsparse knows how to deal with that. Ultimately, I don't think it would be too hard for someone to get this to work. The easiest way might be to directly wrap the ALPSO code instead of going through pyoptsparse.

Comment: Perhaps you could investigate whether or not pyoptsparse does support this. If it does, then I know how to modify the pyoptsparse driver to make it run the cases concurrently.

Comment: I looked into a bit. It looks like pyOptSparse should theoretically work with it, but I get an error when I run with the option because at some point the obj value becomes a tuple. I'll look at it some more when I get another chance.